# How do I get properties from text document

Tags: applescript

I want to make an Applescript that gets a text from a text-document like this:

```
property fooBar : [insert string from text document]

tell application "Terminal"
    set currentTab to do script "echo" & fooBar
end tell
```

How do I do this?

Comment: I´m not sure, what you mean: is it that you want to run a command in Terminal that receives its options by reading them from a text document? Also, is there a reason you do not use `do shell script "echo " & fooBar` ?

Comment: Do you want to read text file properties or its contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't quite understand exactly what you're trying to do, I think you're attempting to use the contents of a text document to set the title of a Terminal tab. If that's the case, this will do so, you don't need a call to do shell script.

```
property foo : missing value

set fileRef to open for access (alias "Aslan:Users:chuck:Desktop:file.txt")
set foo to read fileRef
close access fileRef

tell application "Terminal" to set custom title of selected tab of window 1 to foo
```

Note that if that's all you want to do, the property line isn't needed.